# Reading 4 bits without losing information

Tags: c#, stream, bit

I have come across a problem I cannot seem to solve.
I have a type of file "ASDF", and in their header I can get the necessary information to read them. The problem is that one of the "fields" is only 4 bits long.

So, lets say it's like this:

- From bit 0 to 8 it's the index of the current node (I've read this already)
- From 8 to 16 it's the index for the next node (Read this as well)
- From bit 16 to 20 Length of the content (string, etc..)

So my problem is that if I try to read the "length" with a bytereader I will be losing 4 bits of information, or would be "4 bits off". Is there any way to read only 4 bits?

Comment: You'll have to modify or wrap your bytereader to remember the extra four bits and return them for the next call (plus extra bits read from the next byte as necessary, etc.)

Comment: Just not use a ByteReader (what's that anyway) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read this byte as you read the others then apply a bitmask of 0x0F

For example

```
byte result = (byte)(byteRead & 0x0F);
```

this will preserve the lower four bits in the result.

if the needed bits are the high four then you could apply the shift operator

```
byte result = (byte)((byteRead & 0x0F) >> 5);
```

Comment: My concern is that after I read the "byte", my field is from bit 20, and not 24. Is there anyway I can shift a streamreader or just read 4 bits? Otherwise I'll be reading all the information wrong :/

Comment: Your streamreader reads the full byte, not only 4 bits. You apply the mask after the read. Your streamreader is already at the third byte of your file.